# Is there a way to override OmniAuth default configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

When an error occures on authentication in OmniAuth, `fail!` is called, and in turn calls the Proc defined in OmniAuth::Configuration.

I'd like to override the `on_failure` Proc, to redirect with a more informative error message.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/569 - [one of the posts](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/569#issuecomment-4317056) provides an example of overriding `on_failure`.